# Postgres sql query to update the json set of second level key

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the postgres row as jsonb, and the value as foll{
"value": {
"apple": false,
"ball": true,
"cat": false
}
}ows

```
{
    "value": {
        "a": false,
        "b": true,
        "c": false
    }
}
```

I want to the second level keys (a,b,c) something like

```
{
    "value": {
        "apple": false,
        "ball": true,
        "cat": false
    }
}
```

How do I do this using postgresql

I couldn't able to find the examples to update the second level keys

expecting the updated response like{
"value": {
"apple": false,
"ball": true,
"cat": false
}
}

Comment: Please don't tag your question mysql if you are asking about PostgreSQL or another brand of database. Tagging questions accurately is important because it attracts the people best able to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cte` to associate the new key names with the old, and then update and aggregate with `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
with cte(o_id, n_id) as (
   select 'a', 'apple'
   union all
   select 'b', 'ball'
   union all
   select 'c', 'cat'
)
update tbl set js = jsonb_build_object('value', (select jsonb_object_agg(c.n_id, v.value) 
  from jsonb_each(js -> 'value') v join cte c on c.o_id = v.key) || coalesce(
     (select jsonb_object_agg(v.key, v.value) from jsonb_each(js -> 'value') v 
      where not exists (select 1 from cte c where c.o_id = v.key)), '{}'::jsonb));
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nZB0eiwf).

Comment: Hi Ajax,
This query works fine, but it removes the values other than this,
for example:
if my jsonb has 
{
    "value": {
        "a": false,
        "b": true,
        "c": false,
"d":true,
"e":false
    }
}

This query removes the d and e values from the json set,
after running this query the jsonb value was like
{
    "value": {
        "apple": false,
        "ball": true,
        "call": false,
    }
}

Any suggestions to not affect those values?

Comment: @Riyaz Please see my recent edit.